# How to get local system date and time in sharepoint 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, server, timezone

Here my workflow is running on server time,It's a VM server. Now I want to run my workflow with my local system date and time. For example if my workflow is running on a server which is in USA base time and my local system time is based on Indian time. Now my workflow should run by my system time not on server time. How can I do it? Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.